# Error when I launch "@Web method" with Model as return type

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jena, semantic-web

I'm using Netbeans and I'm following this the instructions in [*Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services*](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html).  I am currently working on a method that I would be exposed as a WebMethod that, given two input strings, returns a **Model** (an interface defined in Jena). In this way, I would like to print my model.

```
/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "Prova_WS")
@Stateless()
public class Prova_WS {
    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
    public Model operation(@WebParam(name = "f") String f, @WebParam(name = "f1") String f1) {
        //to be

        return model;
    }
}
```

Given that probably makes little sense to give as a return value of type **Model**, I get a error when I launch **Test WS Service**. In fact, I get this error in Italian language:

> Errore durante la generazione degli artifact per il seguente WSDL http://localhost:8080/Prova_WS/Prova_WS?WSDL
>
> La possibile causa può essere il richiamo di https quando lapplicazione non è configurata per la sicurezza

I noticed that if for example I change the method with return type **int**, I notice that I don't get the same error.
Why? What am I wrong?

Comment: You need to tell the system how to encode a Model so it can be sent over the wire.  It's not built-in - you'll need to write the code/configuration.

Comment: Ok, How I can tell the system how to encode a Model?

Comment: No one knows how to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a Jena `Model` does not appear in the list of default [Types Supported by JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnazc.html) and that you may need to [Use a custom class as return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028835/2528639). `Model` does not conform to the Java Bean specification, and it does not have any JaxB annotations, so you will need to find out if your web-services library allows you the luxury of creating a custom serialization yourself.

If you can use a String return-type, you can serialize your model using Jena's internal methods, and then return the resulting string:

```java
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
model.write(out, "RDF/XML");
return new String(out.toByteArray());
```

On the client-side, you'll need to be careful to convert that String back to a Jena `Model` if you want to use the Jena API client side.

```
final ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
model.read(in, null, "RDF/XML");
```